# Get-Credential Creating a String Object instead of PSCredential Object (Powershell)

Tags: .net, winforms, powershell

I'm trying to understand why some of my code doesn't work. The idea (for the program) is for me to use the current user for an action, unless that user clicks a button to change the creds they use for the commit action. I can skin this cat another way, but I've become very curious why a piece of code seems to have 2 different results. Here it is (note that all the write-host entries are me trying to track the flow):

```
try{
        $current_credentials = Get-Credential -Credential "ACME.COM\"
        write-host $current_credentials.gettype()
    }
    catch{
        $current_Credentials = $Env:Username
        write-host "catch"
    }
    finally{
        write-host $current_credentials.gettype()
        if($current_Credentials.Gettype().name -eq "PSCredential"){
            $Label_Credentials_Data.Text = $current_Credentials.username
            write-host "PSCred"
        }
        elseif($current_Credentials.Gettype().name -eq "String"){
            $Label_Credentials_Data.Text = $current_Credentials
            write-host "elseif"
        }
        else{
            $Label_Credentials_Data.Text = "ERROR!"
        }
        $Label_Credentials_Data.refresh()
    }
```

Now a few notes: $current_Credentials is first initialised as $env:username. The object $Label_Credentials_Data is a System.Windows.Forms.Label object type.

To test this I spun up another Powershell terminal, initialised $current_credentials the usual way, and made a ps object with property 'text' and method 'refresh' (just so the code would work as is).

If I run the above code in its script, the label text becomes "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" but if I run it by copying and pasting in a new terminal window, I correctly get the $current_credentials.username value. The gettype in the script returns System.String twice, but in the other terminal I get System.Management.Automation.PSCredential twice.

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong here. I even wrapped the copied code into a function to see if that was related.

Script:

```
System.String
System.String
elseif
```

Copied and Pasted:

```
System.Management.Automation.PSCredential
System.Management.Automation.PSCredential
PSCred
```

EDIT: For future readers- there was some code here that was referenced in comments. Check edit history for data.

Comment: Is any of this code embedded inside a block, or a `[ScriptBlock]` object, or invoked using `&` or `Invoke-Expression` or `Invoke-Command`?

Comment: It sounds like we need more context. From what you say I would assume that something is attempting to convert the PSCredential object to text, and not the username value of it. Also, a better test would be `if($current_Credentials -is [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential])`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Thanks I'll use that. It didn't change how that code block is behaving though. Unfortunately I'm not sure what more context I can provide. The script is very basic. This code block sits under an Add_Click method for a Windows.Forms.Button which is on a form, which is created within a function, which is called during 'main'. Thanks to updating my conditional logic I found another location where I made the same test twice (if blah -eq string, else if blah -eq string)

Comment: I'm confused. I ran your test code, and when changing user, the label is showing correctly. What exactly is wrong?

Comment: Same as ojk here, I am unable to replicate the issue. What version of PowerShell are you using? I'm on v4 here, on Win8.1, and wonder if that may be the difference. Is it feasible to upgrade that in your environment?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician v2: "Major" 2, "Minor" 0, "Build" -1, "Revision -1" ($PSVersiontable.PSVersion). So probably a bug they fixed in later versions. Sadly, updating is probably not an option. I guess the good news is my logic wasn't wrong, but the bad news is I have to find another way.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not an answer, but it's too much for a comment. My best guess is that you are having some sort of Scope issue. It sounds like it is somehow getting the System.String object type that the object originally was when you set it to $env:username. Here're my suggestions:

Not what I would recommend, but you could actually make it a string. Username, as a property, as the System.String type. You could pipe your Get-Credentials command to `| Select -ExpandProperty UserName` and that would result in `$current_credentials` being a string still. The issue is that if you want to actually use those credentials that the user just specified you have discarded the actual PSCredential object in lieu of just keeping the UserName string, so you would have to have them enter the credentials again later.

What I would recommend is to use another variable for the credentials, and then pass the UserName property off to $current_credentials. Something like:

```
try{
    $tmpCreds = Get-Credential -Credential "ACME.COM\"
    $current_credentials = $tmpCreds.UserName
}
catch{
    $current_Credentials = $Env:Username
}
finally{
    $Label_Credentials_Data.Text = $current_Credentials
    $Label_Credentials_Data.refresh()
}
```

Comment: I'm not really looking for a work-around, this method was a workaround in the first place. I'm confident I can do that through other ways. The primary reason for asking the question was trying to understand a situation that I couldn't understand for myself. That is, why is a PSCredential object turning into a string when in my code but remaining an object if I copy and paste that code into a terminal.

The reason I needed this check in the first place is because I have to decide whether to prompt the user for a pass. Some users execute the script under the right permissions to start with.

Comment: And the reason for testing whether it was a string or a PSObject is because I need to decide whether to add a -Credential parameter to a cmdlet. If the user wants to execute it under their permissions, there is no point to prompting them. If they want to change, I need to know they changed it so that I can add the parameter. So I'll just use a simple boolean variable and update the text as needed with another variable. Thanks for taking the time to answer.